# How do i download images onto device to be able to set them as a Wallpaper

Tags: android, download, picasso, wallpaper

Is there a way I can download images on android and locate them on the device after the image is downloaded set as a new wallpaper with a click from a button.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand the point that why this question is downvoted.

Comment: @FaisalShaikh Oh, should I try to re explain it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ImageRequest imgRequest = new ImageRequest(url, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Bitmap _bitmapScaled) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        _bitmapScaled.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);

        //you can create a new file name "test.jpg" in sdcard folder.
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + File.separator + "test.jpg")
        f.createNewFile();
        //write the bytes in file
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());

        // remember close de FileOutput
        fo.close();


    }
    }, 0, 0, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, 
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
       //do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Alot! I'll try it out.

Comment: Sure.. approve the answer if this would help you.

Comment: I found the answer on a other post (finally) :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/24650151/5487135